# Check iOS app state from UNNotificationServiceExtension [Swift]

Tags: ios, swift, ios-extensions

I'm using `UNNotificationServiceExtension` in my Swift app for iOS and it is working OK. For special cases I need to know if my app is running when the method `didReceive` from `UNNotificationServiceExtension` is getting called. I tried writing to `UserDefaults` a bool value that indicates the app state, which is being modified by `AppDelegate` events, for example setting it to false when `applicationWillTerminate` is called, but sometimes app can be killed by system without calling `applicationWillTerminate`, so my variable in `UserDefaults` will indicate that app is still alive. Is there any better/smarter way to reach the main app state from iOS `UNNotificationServiceExtension`?

Answer (score -2):

if you have implemented/override `didReceive` of the `UNNotificationServiceExtension` in `AppDelegate` then, there you can simply check like this

`let state = UIApplication.shared.applicationState`

Comment: No, it won't work. I get following error: 'shared' is unavailable: Use view controller based solutions where appropriate instead

Comment: where are you accessing `didReceive`?

Comment: I think it's not possible!

Comment: @NeelBhasin in my class that inherits from UNNotificationServiceExtension. It's in different package by iOS architecture, so I can't reach UIApplication.shared in such an obvious way